# Why is copying a directory with Ansible so slow?

Tags: scp, ansible

I'm using Ansible to copy a directory (900 files, 136MBytes) from one host to another:

```yaml
---
- name: copy a directory
      copy: src={{some_directory}} dest={{remote_directory}}
```

This operation takes an incredible 17 minutes, while a simple `scp -r <src> <dest>` takes a mere 7 seconds.

I have tried the Accelerated mode, which according to the [ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_acceleration.html), but to no avail.

> can be anywhere from 2-6x faster than SSH with ControlPersist enabled, and 10x faster than paramiko.

Comment: I am aware that it does an MD5 hash and validates it but that the time you're seeing would see very large.

Comment: @CatManDo runs sha1, actually, and that isn't responsible (even though it was my first guess).

Answer (score 122, accepted):

TLDR: use `synchronize` instead of `copy`.

Here's the `copy` command I'm using:

```
- copy: src=testdata dest=/tmp/testdata/
```

As a guess, I assume the sync operations are slow. The [files module documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/copy_module.html) implies this too:

> The "copy" module recursively copy facility does not scale to lots (>hundreds) of files. For alternative, see synchronize module, which is a wrapper around rsync.

Digging into the source shows [each file is processed with SHA1](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/files/copy.py#L170). That's [implemented using hashlib.sha1](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/5853828ca51341b5f2d89ade561761e0b749bc46/v2/ansible/utils/hashing.py#L27). A local test implies that only takes 10 seconds for 900 files (that happen to take 400mb of space).

So, the next avenue. The copy is handled with [module_utils/basic.py's atomic_move method](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/5bc81f9ae7a0b13dab8a741081261660f1080727/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py#L1288). I'm not sure if accelerated mode helps (it's a [mostly-deprecated feature](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_acceleration.html#you-might-not-need-this)), but I tried [pipelining](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#pipelining), putting this in a local `ansible.cfg`:

```
[ssh_connection]
pipelining=True
```

It didn't *appear* to help; my sample took 24 minutes to run . There's obviously a loop that checks a file, uploads it, fixes permissions, then starts on the next file. That's a lot of commands, even if the ssh connection is left open. Reading between the lines it makes a little bit of sense- the "file transfer" can't be done in pipelining, I think.

So, following the hint to use the `synchronize` command:

```
- synchronize: src=testdata dest=/tmp/testdata/
```

That took 18 seconds, even with `pipeline=False`. Clearly, the `synchronize` command is the way to go in this case.

Keep in mind `synchronize` uses rsync, which defaults to mod-time and file size. If you want or need checksumming, add `checksum=True` to the command. Even with checksumming enabled the time didn't really change- still 15-18 seconds. I verified the checksum option was on by running `ansible-playbook` with `-vvvv`, that can be seen here:

```
ok: [testhost] => {"changed": false, "cmd": "rsync --delay-updates -FF --compress --checksum --archive --rsh 'ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' \"testdata\" \"user@testhost:/tmp/testdata/\"", "msg": "", "rc": 0, "stdout_lines": []}
```

Comment: Is there no way for the copy module to be faster? This seems like a bug in copy for it to be so slow?

Comment: Once you've switched to `synchronize` over `copy`, you'll need to specify `rsync_opts` if you use rsync/ssh with different ports/users/configs: https://hairycode.org/2016/02/22/using-a-custom-ssh-config-with-ansibles-synchronize-module/

Comment: What if I want to copy a directory locally, i.e., using the `copy` module with setting `remote_src: yes`? It is likely that `synchronize` cannot be used in this situation.

Comment: You deserve a drink mate, Nice answer

Comment: This is the way to go!! Reduced my time to send over my vim dotfiles and color schemes from 175 and 157 seconds to 0.19s and 0.17s (tested with profile_tasks callback). I can't believe how many *MINUTES* I've spent watching that thing until we implemented this. NOTE: It may be helpful to instruct a 'file' task to set the user and group permissions after the synchronize operation is done (user/group functionality is not useful in synchronize module).

Comment: @DanielCompton, Copy does a ton more than just copy. It handles decrypting vault files too (synchronize doesn't), so it has to do a bunch of individual parsing of the files before it gets to the actual transfer.

Answer (score 20):

`synchronize` configuration can be [difficult](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20synchronize%20become) in environments with `become_user`. For one-time deployments you can archive source directory and copy it with `unarchive` module:

```
- name: copy a directory
  unarchive:
    src: some_directory.tar.gz
    dest: {{remote_directory}}
    creates: {{remote_directory}}/indicator_file
```

Comment: And how to archive local directory? `archive` seems to support only remote folders.

Comment: This answer is not suitable for maintaining remote directory in sync with ever-changing local one. It assumes that the local version is a kind of immutable image, which needs to be deployed only once. In that case one can archive it with `tar -cvpzf `, then put resulting archive into `files/` subfolder of a playbook and then use `unarchive` module for faster deployment, faster than `scp` in the question.

Comment: I know, thanks. Syncing and immutable overrides are two different things and I happen to need the latter. For the interest of potential readers, I solved the problem with `archive` by using `delegate_to`.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution I have found is to just zip the folder and use the `unarchive` module.

450 MB folder finished in 1 minute.

---

```
unarchive:
   src: /home/user/folder1.tar.gz
   dest: /opt
```

Comment: ... and where's the difference to the answer by @void?

Answer (score 2):

Providing the `main.yml` task conventions

```
- name: "Copy Files"
  synchronize:
    src: <source>
    dest: <destination>
    rsync_opts:
      - "--chmod=F755" # provide here give also permission
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons is that it decrypts vault files on copy, and this causes a lot of overhead as it scans each file and potentially does decryption.

Answer (score -2):

Also, using Mitogen https://github.com/mitogen-hq/mitogen/ can help, but it doesn't support modern Ansible versions (>6) for now, and has some compatibility issues. Also it's a great solution when hundreds of files need to be templated/copied faster.

Example Ansible task with `connection:local` benchmark for just 545 files:

```yaml
- name: build-artifacts | copy artifact files to installer
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "{{ artifact_tmp_dir.path }}/{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ current_installer_directory }}/{{ artifact.installer_path }}"
    mode: "0644"
  loop: "{{ artifact.src_file_list }}"
```

```
# without mitogen
build-artifacts : build-artifacts | copy artifact files to installer -- 391.72s

# with mitogen
build-artifacts : build-artifacts | copy artifact files to installer --- 32.69s
```

Answer (score -5):

While `synchronize` is more preferable in this case than `copy`, it’s baked by rsync. It means that drawbacks of rsync (client-server architecture) are remained as well: CPU and disc boundaries, slow in-file delta calculations for large files etc. Sounds like for you the speed is critical, so I would suggest you look for a solution based on peer-to-peer architecture, which is fast and easily scalable to many machines. Something like BitTorrent-based, Resilio Connect.