# Slow copy between VMs in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

We have a new Azure implementation we're working with. Right now we're copying files around and getting set up. I have a 30GB SQL backup I needed to move from one virtual machine to another virtual machine. We have them networked.

I started copying and it came flying across but then about halfway through it's just completely stalled. It jumps down to 0MB/s then up to 15-20 for a bit then back down. Attached is a screenshot of the copy dialog with the speed graph. You can see how it dropped off completely.

Any idea why that would happen?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you copying within the same region?

Comment: And how are you copying?

Comment: Yes, copying within the same region.  Copying across the network.  I shared a drive and I'm connectin using   \\ourweb.cloudapp.net\r$

Comment: It seems that the traffic is getting routed through internet, you should rathr use the private IP of ourweb.cloudapp.net

Comment: Did you set up your file share using Azure File Storage (using the files services under your storage container see: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/ Once you set up the file share, simply map that same storage container to both machines, one writes, the other reads. No need to copy.  If you need a step-by-step I can add an answer for you!

Answer (score 0):

the best way i figured to transfer large files between azure and other places, is copy everything to azure's blob (i use files) and back.
The way to copy from and to that storage is **azcopy**. It is extremely fast comparing to all the other method iv'e tried.

another option i haven't tried:
[Why is copying a directory with Ansible so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985334/why-is-copying-a-directory-with-ansible-so-slow/27995384)