# How to prevent ToCToU issue when using Ansible's file module?

Tags: ansible, tocttou

My work environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Ansible 2.6.3
- Ansible Playbook 2.6.3
- Python 2.7.6

I'm writing an Ansible playbook which contains a task that creates a symbolic link that points to a directory somewhere else. The task uses the [`file` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/file_module.html) (I simplified the code for convenience of discussion):

```
- name: Link the app configuration.
  file:
    path: "/home/username/appConfig.lnk"
    src: "/usr/share/app_name/appConfig"
    state: link
    force: no
  become: no
```

If the task is executed successfully, a symbolic link `/home/username/appConfig.lnk` is created and points to the directory `/usr/share/app_name/appConfiig`.

However, in the real use case, the user is likely to modify the `appConfig.lnk` to point to something else which is the customized configuration that suits their needs. **This is expected and valid** in our use, and the `/usr/share/app_name/appConfig` only tries to provide a usable initial configuration.

Therefore, **I want** the playbook task to only create the `appConfig.lnk` when it does **NOT** exist at all. If the path `/home/username/appConfig.lnk` exists already, regardless if it's a symbolic link to the default configuration, a symbolic link to some other customized configuration, a file, or a directory, **I want to skip the creation.**

However, the `file` module, with `force` set to `no`, behaves like this:

- `path` exists and is a directory: **Fail**.
- `path` exists and is a file: **Fail**.
- `path` exists and is a symbolic link pointing to some other location other than `src`: **Automatically recreate the link to point to `src`**.

To workaround this issue, I added a task to call [`stat` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/stat_module.html) before:

```
- name: Get the app configuration status.
  stat:
    path: "/home/username/appConfig.lnk"
  register: stat_config
  become: no

- name: Link the app configuration.
  when: not stat_config.stat.exists  # <-- New condition
  file:
    path: "/home/username/appConfig.lnk"
    src: "/usr/share/app_name/appConfig"
    state: link
    force: no
  become: no
```

But I think this introduces the [ToCToU issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use), because, although highly unlikely, the `appConfig.lnk` may be deleted right after the `stat` call so the `file` module is skipped and I end up with a system that says everything has been done successfully but the link is NOT created.

So **I'm wondering if there is a way to implement what I want but avoid the possible ToCToU issue.**

Comment: I think you might be happiest using `shell:` rather than the modules, since the logic you described is so complex

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use the "command creates" construct.

```
- name: Create link
  command: ln -s /usr/share/app_name/appConfig /home/username/appConfig.lnk
  args:
    creates: /home/username/appConfig.lnk
```

Discussion about the command module is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259219/creating-a-list-of-directories-with-ansible-with-file-module-is-slow)